# Wrap long source strings to prevent horizontal scrolling in Traducir

Tags: feature-request, status-review, localization, scrolling, traducir

If the source English string is long enough to fit into screen horizontally then either you need to scroll the page or copy source into the edit box to see it entirely. See the GIF to clarification:

> [image]

Could word wrapping please be added for original string so the whole sentence would be visible on screen?

Comment: I believe the same issue happens for long strings in the "current translation" field as well.

Comment: Trivia question: Were the colors of the buttons chosen on purpose? (Blue and yellow. ;))

Comment: @Shadow these are the colors of the flag of the traducir author's home country.

Comment: But there's also green, there's other country with only blue and yellow, so maybe it's a hidden sign of supporting them.

Comment: @Shadow where did you find the green one on the flag of Uruguay?

Comment: Oops, for some reason thought he's from Brazil. Well, so this might indeed explain. :)

Comment: @V2Blast yep, but mostly I do the new translation instead of fixing the old one. Because there's no old.